# ffmpeg: combine -tpad with -ss and -t

Tags: video, ffmpeg

Using ffmpeg with -ss, -t and -tpad, I'm trying to trim a bunch of clips to a fixed length of 6 seconds total: 2 seconds of handle at the beginning + 2 seconds of interest + 2 trailing seconds at the end. Unfortunately some of my input clips do not have 2 trailing seconds at the end or beginning, so I try to pad them with tpad (so the output is always 6 seconds). That kinda works, but now I have my two seconds of interest always in the beginning - not in the middle, like I want to. How can I fix this?

Bonus question: Currently it pads with black.  How could the color option use the first / last frame of video as a still instead?

The code I use (called from Python but it should make no difference for the filterchain):

```
filterchain = "[0:v]tpad=stop=-1,trim=end=6,scale='if(gt(a,1/1),-1,480)':'if(gt(a,1/1),480,-1)',setsar=1,crop=480:480"
subprocess.call(['ffmpeg', '-ss', str(inpoint-2), '-t', '6',
  '-i', input_clip, '-filter_complex', filterchain, '-r', '25',
  '-c:v', 'prores', '-profile:v', '1', '-c:a', 'pcm_s16le',
  '-ar', '48000', "-hide_banner", '-loglevel', 'error', output])
```

Comment: You need to obtain the file's duration and set tpad values accordingly. `ffprobe -v 0 -show_entries format=duration -of compact=p=0:nk=1 file`

Comment: thanks for your answer, this is how i'll do this! : )